# How to sort my objects list by date which is returned from server by a ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I send an Ajax call to server, then server returns me the xml data which contain a **list of objects**. Each object in the list contain a **"date"** attribute.

In the `success` function of the Ajax call, I would like to populate each object in a row of a html table, but before this, I would like to **sort the objects by date ascending order** based on the **"date"** attribute of each object. I am wondering what is the efficient way to do this?

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : MY_URL_1,
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(xml) {

               $(xml).find("DOCUMENT").each(function() {
               var eachXMLdata = $(this);
               var date = eachXMLdata.children("DATE").text();

               // I can check each object's date here
               console.log('date:'+date);

               /*** How to sort the object by date??****/

               //I will show each object in a row of a html table here
               // ...
             });
       }
});
```

As you saw above, I used the `.each()` function in Ajax `success()` function to loop through each object and will show each object in a row of a html table.

Comment: for sure if you can do it SQl then do but otherwise have you seen this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780174/jquery-sorting-an-array

Comment: @Miroprocessor, I sorted it in server side, but for some reason, I got unsorted list anyway, so I am thinking of sort it again on client side

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort JavaScript array of Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421253/sort-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: try to save the list after sorting into another list then return the new list

Comment: @Leem , If I were in your situation , I sorted a list on the server but couldnt retrieve it as expected on the client , that's exactly what I'd be trying to debug . Just a wild guess , maybe the sorted values at some stage during processing end up in an unordered collection .

Answer (score 0):

Well , If you do have to do it on client side , construct Date objects with the text , and then you can the getTime() function to get the milliseconds since epoch , which should be easily comaparable .

Refer below for the Date object API 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp